# Como guardar una copia de un archivo "(NombreArchivo(1))" si ya existe uno con el mismo nombre con filestream en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy realizando un programa en el que creo un pdf con cierta informacion identificado por un numero codigo, quisiera que al crearse otro pdf con el mismo nombre , este cree una copia (sin borrar el primero), justo como hace Windows , que agrega un "(1)" alfinal del nombre para diferenciarlos, actualmente estoy ocupando esta instruccion, pero si ya existe un archivo con el mismo nombre simplemente lo sobre escribe

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\PDFs\remision " + orden + ".pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(me gustaria dejar esto en los comentarios pero no me dan los puntos, soy nuevo)
```

Podrias corroborar si el nombre el archivo ya existe con `File.Exists(filePath)`, y en ese caso le pones un nombre distinto?

Comment: A tu respuesta le falta muy poco para ser una respuesta completa.  Talvez deberias borrar el comentario y poner un ejemplo de como lo harias.

Comment: No pasa nada, como aclare mas arriba, quisiera hacer un comentario pero no me daban los puntos. Es aplicar usar una estructura de decisión respecto a lo que devuelva ``File.Exists(filePath)``, y si el resultado es negativo, que haga lo que hace. Guardar el nombre como lo esta haciendo. Si no es así, intentaria guardarlo con un nombre distinto, pero llamando recursivamente a esta misma función para que vuelva a verificar si el nombre que voy a poner para no repetir, también se encuentra. Es muy loca mi idea? Pero estoy en el trabajo, que la codee otro, lo mio fue una opinión a modo de ayuda, ja

Comment: Pues si, al final lo hice con esa funcion y salio justo como lo que necesitaba